# Content of the page back to normal (as it was before) when the checkbox input is unchecked

Tags: javascript, html, css, checkbox, onchange

SO I wanted to change few contents of the page when the checkbox input is checked and bring everything back to it was before when the checkbox is unchecked.

```
    <div class="switch">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox" onchange="darkmode(this)" />
    </div>

    <section id="section">
    <p>This is a line</p>
    </section>
```

```
    <script>
        function darkmode(checkboxElem) {
          if (checkboxElem.checked) {
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = "black";
            document.getElementById("checkbox").style.borderColor = "white";
            document.getElementById("section").style.color ="white"; 
          }else {
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
            document.getElementById("checkbox").style.borderColor = "black";
            document.getElementById("section").style.color ="black"; 
          }
        }   
    </script>
```

I figured I can do that by giving value to every content that was changed. In the 'else' statement I will have to give every content it's the value of 'as it was before' Doing this will take a lot of time and I will have to write everything twice (in CSS and Javascript).

If there is a way to bring everything to default when the checkbox is unchecked without without giving every element their pervious value. Please, let me know.

Thank you

Comment: Any problems, errors?

Comment: do a different approach. make chanegs by adding a class to an element and remove it with JS. Then you do the chanegs with styling the class through CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest solution would be to add and remove a class to the body as in the snippet below. Then you delcare all styling for the darkmode within the css. Its important, that it is written at the bottom of the normal css.

```js
function darkmode(checkboxElem) {
  var darkMode = document.body;
  if (checkboxElem.checked) {
    darkMode.classList.add("dark-mode");
  } else {
    darkMode.classList.remove("dark-mode");
  }
}
```

```css
.dark-mode {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox" onchange="darkmode(this)" />
  </div>

  <section id="section">
    <p>This is a line</p>
  </section>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think a most simple and clear solution is design your dark mode style linked to a body css class and toggle that class using onchange event directly.

I hope that solution helps you.

```css
body.dark-mode{
  background-color:black;
}
  body.dark-mode>h1{
    color:red;
  }
  body.dark-mode>p{
    color:white;
  }
```

```html
<body>
 <input type='checkbox' onchange='document.body.classList.toggle("dark-mode");'>
 <h1>Heading 1</h1>
 <p>Paragraph 1</p>
 ...
</body>
```